# Rails link_to helper relative to namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a blog engine with a backend, where the backend routes are namespaced under `admin` and the frontend under `public`. Now I would like to share some of the views between the two namespaces.

Is there a DRY way to instruct `link_to` to generate urls relative to the current namespace (e.g. a link made with `posts_path()` where the controller is `admin/home#index` should point to `/admin/posts`, but the same link under the controller `public/home#index` should point to `/public/posts`), so I can use the same view for both controllers?

I see I could solve it using conditionals, and using `admin_posts_path` and `public_posts_path` respectively, but that adds a lot of clutter to the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something we did in an API project was not to use namespace, rather to use scopes like this:

```
scope '/:type', constraints: { type: /(admin|public)/ } do
  resources :posts
end
```

Then in your views, you'd do:

```
# The :type param should be inferred from the route, but you could be explicit as such:
link_to 'Posts', posts_path(type: params[:type])
```

That should always link appropriately to your public and admin posts

Answer (score 0):

Use `scope` to do it.

Read more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers

```
scope 'admin' do
  resources :posts, as: 'admin_posts'
end
 
resources :posts
# the same to public
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting your links as variables in your controllers if you intend to use the same view.

Like so

```
Admin::PostController < Parent
  def show 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @posts_link = admin_posts_path #This is the link
    render "shared_path/show"
  end
end
```

and

```
Public::PostController < Parent
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @posts_link = public_posts_path #This is also the link
    render "shared_path/show"
  end
end
```

and

```
#in the view path/show.html.erb
<%= link_to "Posts", @posts_link %>
```

Comment: This answer actually helped me out a ton. If you have paths that require parameters, make sure to use it like so:
`@posts_link = :public_posts_path` and `@posts_links_params = ['param1', 'param2']`.  Then in your view:

`<%= link_to 'Posts', send(@posts_link, *@post_links_params) %>`

That way you can have different links & different parameters set by different controllers for the same view!

Sorry about formatting, it's pretty limited in comments.